# MySql Group function error

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mysql-error-1111

```
select nume,model,sum(km_sosire-km_plecare) as 'km_parcursi' from masina m
inner join (foaie_parcurs f inner join angajat a using(id_angajat)) using(id_masina)
where sum(km_sosire-km_plecare)>100
group by a.nume,m.model
order by sum(km_sosire-km_plecare);
```

Error: **Invalid use of group function**

Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use aggregates in the where clause.  That's what "having" is for.

```
select nume,model,sum(km_sosire-km_plecare) as 'km_parcursi' from masina m
inner join (foaie_parcurs f inner join angajat a using(id_angajat)) using(id_masina)
group by a.nume,m.model
having sum(km_sosire-km_plecare)>100
order by sum(km_sosire-km_plecare);
```

Comment: FYI, you can use aliases in the `HAVING` clause so this will work too: `having km_parcursi > 100`